# MongoDB via Brew Services "undefined method `plist_startup'"

Tags: ruby, mongodb, homebrew, plist

When I run MongoDB, I usually start it manually (i.e. it's not part of my login startup items) and I'm good about stopping the service before I shutdown.

I recently restarted my laptop and received an error upon running:

```bash
brew services run mongodb/brew/mongodb-community
```

The error message reads:

> Error: undefined method `plist_startup' for #<Formula mongodb-community (stable) /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/mongodb/homebrew-brew/Formula/mongodb-community.rb>

I'm not entirely sure what happened. I haven't installed any major updates or made any modifications to my environment.

### What I've Tried

I completely uninstalled MongoDB before installing it again:

```bash
# Uninstall each component of mongodb-community...
brew uninstall mongodb/brew/mongodb-community
brew uninstall mongodb/brew/mongodb-database-tools
brew uninstall mongosh

# Reinstall all of the above...
brew install mongodb/brew/mongodb-community
```

##### Current Install

`mongod --version`

```json
db version v7.0.2
Build Info: {
    "version": "7.0.2",
    "gitVersion": "02b3c655e1302209ef046da6ba3ef6749dd0b62a",
    "modules": [],
    "allocator": "system",
    "environment": {
        "distarch": "x86_64",
        "target_arch": "x86_64"
    }
}
```

##### Could be Homebrew...?

I'll be honest, sometimes on these late nights, I'm on autopilot. I may or may not have run a `brew upgrade` at some point. I'll look into whether or not this happened. In the meantime, when I get the log for MongoDB in Homebrew, I don't even see a commit that would have impacted me:

```bash
brew log mongodb/brew/mongodb-community

# Yields...

commit f33a59b6642f6a9f47f84b390dd71c386998cce6
Author: Zack Winter <zack.winter@mongodb.com>
Date:   Wed Oct 4 23:24:26 2023 +0000

    Update paths with mr script

commit 7f3db6dbe9231300cc61645c68686a970b575f1f
Author: Zack Winter <zack.winter@mongodb.com>
Date:   Tue Oct 3 20:00:06 2023 +0000

    SERVER-80537 update formulas for 7.0.1 release

commit 5055c34131148681885ea2241abccfc603596295
Author: Alexander Neben <alexander.neben@mongodb.com>
Date:   Fri Aug 18 10:54:02 2023 -0700
```

Comment: What version of Homebrew are you running when you encounter this error?

Comment: Also please consider reconciling the statement "*I haven't installed any major updates or made any modifications to my environment.*" and "*I may or may not have run a brew upgrade at some point.*" now that you have had time to look into whether that happened or not, as those are two conflicting statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently Homebrew updated to 4.2, which changed the way it starts services. It required the mongodb formula to explicitly define a service block, even if just points to the service file.

The fix was merged in https://github.com/mongodb/homebrew-brew/commit/2d0bfe19214d1f5071decd238b29306a6e82fff2

Comment: **Thanks for looking into this, good sir!** I already see the change coming through the `brew upgrade` process.

Answer (score 11):

this dirty hack worked for me:

> edit this file:
>
> `/opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-services/lib/service/formula_wrapper.rb`
>
> change the line:
>
> `@service_startup ||= formula.plist_startup.present?`
>
> to
>
> `@service_startup ||= formula.plist_name.present?`

Comment: Is this content quoted from some other location? If yes, from what source? If not, why is it using quote formatting?

Comment: Also what does this _do_? Please explain your answers.

Comment: ChatGPT4 via Bing gave me this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had this issue and went through the whole list above.  This is what worked for me and my mac.  I went to Finder and found MongoDB.  When I clicked on the application, it states that my computer thought it was malicious.  I had to right click and manually allow it to open.  Then when I went back to Compass, I was able to connect.

Comment: Thanks for the input - I might try that if my current resolution fails. FWIW - The problem we're seeing here is with the MongoDB service itself to be leveraged through code and scripts, not the GUI editor (MongoDB Compass).

Answer (score 0):

## <s>Start Script Changed</s>

## `FAIL...see [UPDATE] at the bottom`

I'm not sure how or why, but it seems like the startup script had to change. Here are the steps I took to get MongoDB back up and running again, though I would recommend just skipping down to trying an alternative to starting MongoDB, first.

### Reinstall MongoDB

I first tried forcing a reinstall of MongoDB, via Homebrew. My efforts, of course, were to no avail:

```bash
brew reinstall mongodb/brew/mongodb-community
```

### Uninstalled Homebrew

This was annoying because it basically disconnects itself from anything it ever installed. If you want to blast through updates as per usual, you'll have to reinstall everything again. It's easy enough to make a list and run a batch install:

```bash
brew leaves
```

**But, be careful**: that doesn't include all your casks. I forgot to make my list and check it twice this holiday season. If you want to have a nicely wrapped Homebrew, be sure to run this as well:

```bash
brew list --cask   #add the "-1" to the end if you want a vertical list.
```

### Reinstalled An Old Version of Homebrew

I went back and found the installer package for `Homebrew-4.1.23.pkg` and just installed via the GUI when I couldn't figure out how to install a previous version from a script.

Unfortunately, before I ran any kind of `brew install ...` commands, I forgot to set this variable:

```bash
export HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1;
```

....soooooo, ya. Once I ran any brew command it upgraded me right back to where I started thinking there was an issue. *Aren't you glad you skipped to the end instead of following these steps?*

##### Alternate Method

**FWIW** - When it came time to reinstall MongoDB, I followed a different path than I'm used to; *different than what I have scripted for system setups*. I used the method described in the [MongoDB docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/#installing-mongodb-7.0-edition-edition):

```bash
brew install mongodb-community@7.0
```

## Change MongoDB Startup Scripts

In my profile script(s) I have a few functions for managing things like the start/stop of MongoDB. For example, my script to `run` MongoDB looks like this:

```bash
function mongo-run {
    pid=$(ps -A | grep '[mon]god' | awk '{printf "%d", $1}');
    if [[ -z $pid ]];then
        brew services run mongodb/brew/mongodb-community;
    else
        printf "
        ${txtblu}Mongo is already running with process ID ${bldblu}$pid${txtrst}\n";
    fi
}
```

...and all I did was change to this:

```bash
function mongo-run {
    pid=$(ps -A | grep '[mon]god' | awk '{printf "%d", $1}');
    if [[ -z $pid ]];then
        brew services run mongodb-community;
    else
        printf "
        ${txtblu}Mongo is already running with process ID ${bldblu}$pid${txtrst}\n";
    fi
}
```

In case you missed it:

```bash
# This...
brew services run mongodb/brew/mongodb-community;

# changed to this...
brew services run mongodb-community;
```

#### `Pretty ridiculous, right?`

Oh well. It's all working again, for now.

## UPDATE

I don't know what I did, exactly, but I am running into that original error message again.

Oddly enough, after I ran the Homebrew command(s) to remove and cleanup the MongoDB-related stuff, I ran the `brew services run mongodb-community` command and got the *SAME* error message. ...as if the `.rb` script wasn't removed after I ran the uninstall and cleanup commands.

I eventually got it completely reinstalled again (MongoDB, that is - not Homebrew) and am still seeing the error.

- I also made sure there were no other Ruby installs on my Mac, just the default `v2.6`.

Comment: I get the same error regardless of what name I use for the service to start, any other ideas?

Comment: Yeah, I also ran the commands from the official docs, also re-tried it by uninstalling, steps here, yet still no luck.

Comment: Temporary fix to which I probably might get a downvote.. and I do not suggest this, but you can just comment out 
/opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-services/lib/service/formula_wrapper.rb

where the line is:


@service_startup ||= formula.plist_startup.present?

Answer (score 0):

On a mac m1 a fix I did was to add the command to start up the database manually. With the following command `mongod --config /opt/homebrew/etc/mongod.conf`

### To run automatically

Step 1: Find where your mongod.conf is, it should be in the etc folder, but depends on which chip you have. So do `brew --prefix` to check. I am in an m1, so mine is in the aforementioned, but yours may say `/usr/local` in that case check `/usr/local/etc` for it.

Step 2. Open up your `.zshrc` file. This should be in your home directory. If you are not on a zsh then check for a `.bashrc` file.

Step 3. At the end of your rc file add. `mongod --config /opt/homebrew/etc/mongod.conf &` this will run the command to start the database manually every time you open up a terminal. The `&` at the end is to make sure it runs in the background.

This seems to work, it can get annoying as if you want to use compass you need to open up a terminal to start the database. However, I see this as a workaround in the meantime until the devs push an update.

Comment: Won't this run mongo every time I open a new Terminal window? Anyway, the goal here isn't to use MongoDB in a GUI like Compass. It's to leverage it as a service (through code).

Perhaps you could take a look at making a simple function to start/stop the service, like I showed one of my other posts. No need to spin up every time you open a new Terminal window (especially if using multiple Terminal windows, like I usually do).

Answer (score 0):

## Another Option

For now, this has been proving useful. I wanted to remove `root` as the executing user for the service. I'm not sure how useful it is to anyone else, but <sup>(to use the worst phrase any programmer could utter)</sup> *"it works on my machine:"*

```bash
# Be sure to insert your user name in the next line...
sudo brew services run mongodb-community --sudo-service-user <your.user.name>
brew services ls
sudo brew services stop mongodb-community
brew services start mongodb-community
```

### Breakdown

After running the first command, I saw that the service had my user name under it, even though it was not running. In previous attempts, this would always say `root`:

```bash
brew services ls
# Yields...
Name              Status  User       File
docker-machine    none               
mongodb-community started <your.user.name>
```

Out of superstition I ran the third line, in the hopes that something needing cleaned up got cleaned up.

When I ran the last command, to `start` the service, and rebooted my machine, everything worked fine. I've had a couple reboots today and so far so good.

```bash
brew services ls
# After rebooting this yields...
Name              Status  User       File
docker-machine    none               
mongodb-community started <your.user.name> ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist
```

¯\*(ツ)*/¯